# Userscript: Automatically press a button without ID that reload page just once

Tags: javascript, userscripts

So i'm trying to create a userscript for Tampermonkey targeting Crome as the browser.

What i want to do is automatically press a button. There are however several things that makes this more complicated than what i've usually done.

1. When the button gets activated it post a formula to the site, and refresh the site, and i only want to press the buttom once
2. I don't know the name/ID of the table.
3. My script includes several pages so I have to be specific on the ID of the button so that it does not execute on the wrong pages.

So usually i would use:

```
$("select[name=#MyTablename]").val("10");
document.forms[0].submit();
```

This is the code i want to acces:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="List Airports">
```

I was wondering if the right thing to do is acces via xpath

```
//*[@id="body"]/input[4]
```

or via selector

```
#body > input:nth-child(11)
```

and how do I secure that the script does only run on this subpage out of a several on the domain i want to make my script active at.

Also how do I stop the script from keep executing over and over again when the page reload after the automatic click. (I just want to click the button once per time i visit the page)

Comment: You can access this button using attribute selector, for example: `$("[value='List Airports']")`.

Answer (score 0):

1.
You can use GM_setValue and GM_getValue to be sure you already clicked on the button. Example:

```
// Don't forget to include that in your // == UserScript== at the beinning of the script. 
// To learn more about these metadata here: https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block

// @grant  GM_getValue
// @grant  GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==
```

Then use that to submit the form (be sure to include jQuery!):

```
if (!GM_getValue("foo") {
    GM_setValue("foo", "bar");
    $("input[type='submit'][value='yourvalue']").click();
}
```

Don't forget to setup a button to actually reset the values or it'll only works once.

---

2. If there is no other table on the page you can use $("table").

---

3. See 1., you can also read that for more: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/